# Converting data bind values to strings inside foreach knockout

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43tu58xc/3). All I want to do is , convert the values nested in each object literal to a string.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li>
       <span data-bind="text: Name"> </span>

        <span data-bind="text:Id"></span>

    </li>
</ul>



 function AppViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.people = ko.observableArray([{"Name":"RobbStark",Id:1}, {"Name":"JohnSnow",Id:2}]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

I want to use a lookup 
like

```
var valueMap={
    1:"SanJose",
    2:"San Francisco"
}
```

To get output like

```
RobbStark SanJose
JohnSnow San Francisco.
```

How do I convert the observable to a different value inside foreach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is call a javascript function from your text data-binding, passing in the current item ($data) from the for each loop as a parameter.  Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vsbmdgwy/6/)

**Javascript:**

```
var valueMap={
    1:"SanJose",
    2:"San Francisco"
}

 function AppViewModel()
{
    var self = this;

    self.people = ko.observableArray([{"Name":"RobbStark",Id:1}, {"Name":"JohnSnow",Id:2}]);
    self.parsedName = function (item) {
        return item.Name + " " + valueMap[item.Id];
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

**HTML**

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li>
       <span data-bind="text: $root.parsedName($data)"> </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Note #1 under the KnockoutJS [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) contains more information about $data.